# How do you move the contents of the main function to a different function and retain functionality?

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently trying to move the contents of the "main" function to its own function, both so I can repeat things and also to have more options of what happens and when. Once the function is complete, I also want to increase an integer each time something is purchased, so it can be checked with some sort of inventory command.

I've made the mistake of effectively copy-pasting what I previously had in main into what I want to be its own function. Unfortunately, this is actually my first time trying to declare a function other than main that wasn't given to me by other people on this site, so I don't really know how to declare them. I'm guessing the declaration was incorrect/lacked data, causing problems.

The code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Attempting to declare the function early, which is the only thing CS50 has taught me about custom functions thus far.
void itemshop(int buckaroonies);

//Struct given to me in another post
struct item
    {
        string name;
        int price;
        string description;
    };

//Part of aformentioned struct
int find_item(string item_name, struct item items[], size_t num_items)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_items ; i++)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(items[i].name, item_name))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    //Item not available
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    //Item struct
     struct item items[] = {
        {"Matchbox", 50, "They're cheap, and they'll keep you warm."},
        {"Wool Hat", 125, "A nice, handknit, cozy hat. Thank my ma for that!"},
        {"Heavy Coat", 250, "This coat'll keep you cozy through the night no matter the situation!"},
        {"Canned Food", 25, "It don't taste too good, but it'll last you a lifetime. Eat up!"}
    };
    const size_t num_items = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);

    //Integers for items once they are purchased
    int buckaroonies = 500;
    int matchb = 0;
    int woolh = 0;
    int heavyc = 0;
    int canf = 0;

    itemshop(int buckaroonies);
}

//This is probably the worst part, I just copy-pasted what I had in main into this function, and likely declared it incorrectly as well
void itemshop(int buckaroonies)
{
    //Dialogue and selection
    printf("Hey chum, welcome to the item shop. You've got a handful 'o coin on ya, huh?\nYou came to the right place, we got the best wares in town!\n\n");
    printf("Store:\n\nMatchbox - 50\nWool Hat - 125\nHeavy Coat - 250\nCanned Food - 25\n");
    string select = get_string ("What'll it be? You have %i buckaroonies, pal.\n", buckaroonies);
    string description[] = { "They're cheap, and they'll keep you warm.\n", "A nice, handknit, cozy hat. Thank my ma for that!\n", "This coat'll keep you cozy through the night no matter the situation!\n", "It don't taste too good, but it'll last you a lifetime. Eat up!" };


    //Get item details from selection, error comes from here
    int index = find_item(select, items, num_items);

    //Return dialogue based on selected item
    if (-1 == index)
    {
        printf("We aint got that, pal.\n");
    }
    else
        {
            char c = get_char ("That %s'll cost ya %i buckaroonies. %s You want it?\n", items[index].name, items[index].price, items[index].description);

            if(c == 'y' || c == 'Y')

                {
                    printf("Pleasure doing business with you, pal. -%i Buckeroonies\n", items[index].price);
                    buckaroonies = buckaroonies - items[index].price;
                }
            else if (c == 'n' || c == 'N')
                {
                    printf("Alright, feel free to keep browsing.\n");
                }
            else
                {
                    printf("Hey, uh... I don't know what that means.\n");
                }
        }
}
```

The error:

```
itemshop.c:48:14: error: expected expression
    itemshop(int buckaroonies);
             ^
```

Comment: Re “Unfortunately, this is actually my first time trying to declare a function other than main that wasn't given to me by other people on this site, so I don't really know how to declare them. I'm guessing the declaration was incorrect/lacked data”: Do not learn C by reading or interacting on this web site. [Get a book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) Work through the book. Programming is not learned from copying examples like some physical skills can be learned. You need to be taught ideas.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not trying to program professionally, nor am I just copying people's code without researching how it does what it's doing. I'm taking CS50, and this is just me practicing the syntax.

Comment: [Get a book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) Work through the book.

Comment: The basics of C are straightforward and there have been short, easy to follow books on it since 1978 (PDFs and ebooks today as well). It really will make your life easier.

Comment: I do appreciate you guys trying to tell me about alternative resources, but like I said, that's not the route I'm trying to take. As soon as I finish CS50 I plan to dive headfirst into Godot to start game development as a hobby. This isn't really something I plan to use in any other situation.

Comment: So what did you miss in CS50? Are you following it, or are you guessing?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am only past week 1. I started this at the same time as I started the week 2 lecture, which was this morning.

Comment: Well, follow the course step by step, and don't try to run ahead. Also, please don't post rolling updates to the code – CS50 is your tutorial.

Comment: I meant to start it as something simple but it rapidly expanded and outpaced me. There was just more that I thought would be fun to add, so I asked how to do it, and then did it.

Comment: Note that none of the variables defined in `main()` can be accessed outside it because they're not passed to the `itemshop()` function as arguments.  You likely need to include those variables in the function — you might make them file static variables, but global variables are undesirable.

Comment: Well, `voind itemshop()` wasnt a function call, and now `itemshop(int buckaroonies)` at the end of `main` is not a function call either. Your program already has many function calls, like `find_item` and `printf and `strcmp` and `get_char`. Look at them, then look at `itemshop(int buckaroonies)`, write down an explanation of why you put `int` there and not in all these other calls, and read it aloud to the nearest rubber duck.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I put it there because I have no idea how it SHOULD look or work, which is why I asked this question. I thought I made the fact I don't know how to make functions pretty clear, but thank you for your generous contributions to the collective list of non-answers to this question. Instead of answering the question, you told me that the very thing I was asking was somehow self-evident, which it really isn't for someone who's just learning what they're doing. How exactly was this interaction productive for either person involved?

Comment: You're just guessing what to write.  nm is trying to get you to the next level and get you to see the patterns in your code and use logic to understand what you need to write.  You keep writing types in random places where you don't need them.  You ONLY need to write a type when you are declaring/defining a new thing that the compiler doesn't know about yet.  The compiler already knows `buckaroonies` is an `int` so don't write `int` again.

Comment: _Re_ your current problem, `itemshop(int buckaroonies)` doesn't make sense as a _statement_. You probably meant just `itemshop(buckaroonies)`; `backaroonies` is an `int` declared earlier in `main`, so it will pass type-checking and _copy_ 500 into `itemshop` as the parameter, (also called `buckaroonies`.)

Comment: Yes, I am guessing what to write, because I don't know how this works fundamentally. I just want to get this project done and over with so I can get back on track with lecture 2, because the scope of this has gotten drastically out of hand for my current skill level. I am trying to ask what something like this should look like, and I've gotten nothing but snarky or condescending answers telling me that I shouldn't be where I am, **which I already know.** I just want to be done with this project so I can move on.

Comment: The better plan would be to shelve the project until the course has equipped you with the knowledge to complete it. Stick to the course. Do the exercises advised by the course, to solidify what you are learning. You are trying to run before you can walk. At best you'll be writing terrible code and getting into self-taught bad habits, or into cargo cult programming where you copy and use code without really knowing what it does.

Comment: That's probably for the best, but the incomplete code is going to bug me, just sitting in VSCode next to all my other projects. Sorry to drag that on for so long.

Comment: I apologise. My idea was to show you patterns in what you have already wrote, so that you can write the same thing one more time, and arrive at the answer on your own. Which I, in my unbounded foolishness, assumed to be more valuable than somebody giving you a ready-made answer. I'm guilty as charged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic technique to move the contents of `main()` into a function called from `main()` is to change the name of the function and write the new `main()`.  Since your `main()` program ignores all command line arguments, the change would look like this:

**Before**

```
int main(void)
{
    …declarations and code…
}
```

**After**

```
static int old_main(void)
{
    …declarations and code…
    return 0;   // Necessary - only main() gets special treatment
}

int main(void)
{
    return old_main();
}
```

You can then make changes, moving appropriate code from `old_main()` to `main()` and adding parameters to `old_main()` so that it can access the data it needs to work on.

If your program took command line arguments, you'd replace each occurrence of `(void)` with `(int argc, char **arg)`.  However, you'd most likely want to process the command line arguments in the revised `main()`, calling the function to process files named on the command line (or strings specified on the command line).

When I'm working on a problem, I often start out with a `main()` function that includes far too much material, and I end up writing a test harness function based on the original `main()` that can be called repeatedly from the revised `main()`.  You can see an example of this in some code in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub — for example, the files `mds41.c` and `mds43.c` in the [src/so-4715-1134](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4715-1134) sub-directory.
There are numerous other examples in that repo.

Comment: This one was the solution, thank you very much. I'm kinda shocked that it was this simple, but I guess I was just really overcomplicating things. Making functions seemed so much more complicated than this, but it really wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `void itemshop();` at the bottom of main.  That is a declaration, not a function call.  When you call a function, you do NOT write a type (i.e. `void` or `int`) directly before the name of the function.  Carefully compare that line to all the other functions calls in your code (i.e. when you call `printf` or `strcmp`).

Remove `void` and then solve the next error your compile reports to you, which is that you forgot to include an argument to the function.

There might be other problems in your code, which you can diagnose by carefully reading all compiler warnings and error message and/or using a debugger.  I didn't try running your code.

Comment: Note: OP has edited the code in their question, making my answer look like it doesn't make sense.

Comment: That was unintentional, but your answer was also not a complete solution to the problem. What was there was helpful, but doing so only led me to another loop of errors that I do not know how to solve.

Comment: Very essential information nonetheless.

Comment: @Alex: The updated code has replaced `void itemshop();` at the bottom of `main()` with `itemshop(int buckaroonies);`.  That is still an attempt at a function declaration, not a function call.  You don't specify types — return value or argument types — in a function call (unless you're casting something, but casts are enclosed in parentheses).  The call should be just: `itemshop(buckaroonies);`.  Note, though, that you can't access any other values defined in your replacement main — and you can't change the value of `buckaroonies` in `main()` from the `itemshop()` function.